# How would you write feature agnostic code for both AVX2 and AVX512?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, intrinsics, avx2, avx512

One way of doing this would be to create function pointers which conditionally point to different functions depending upon a preprocessor directive which selects the desired feature set.

```
#if defined(__AVX512__)
    void (*func_ptr)() = _mm512_func;
#else
    void (*func_ptr)() = _mm256_func;
#endif

int main()
{
    func_ptr();
    return 0;
}
```

Are there better ways of doing this? Thanks.

Comment: If you're detecting AVX512 only at compile time, you don't need function pointers.  Just `#define func _mm512_func`.  (And only define the version that will actually be called).  Or more simply, don't define different names for the same function at all, just select which definition to compile.

Comment: @PeterCordes I thought function pointers were preferred over macros in the C++ community. But this does the same job. Is this the best way to go? Any other ideas?

Comment: ... or just `#ifdef` around the possible implementations of the same function.

Comment: @NanashiNoGombe - you still have the macros with your suggested function pointer approach, so even if "function pointers over macros" was somehow a rule, this wouldn't get rid of the macros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If you're detecting AVX512 only at compile time, you don't need function pointers.**

The simplest way: don't define different names for the same function at all, just select which definition to compile in the `.cpp` file where you have multiple versions of it.  That keeps the compile-time dispatching isolated to the file that defines the function, not visible to the rest of your code.

```
#ifdef __AVX512F__
void func(float *__restrict a, float *__restrict b) {
 ...  // AVX512 version here
}
#elif defined(__AVX2__) && defined(__FMA__)
void func(float *__restrict a, float *__restrict b) {          // same name
 ...  // AVX2 version here
}
#else
...       // SSE2 or scalar fallback
#endif
```

Although for testing you do probably want to be able to build all versions of it and test + benchmark them against each other, so you might consider   using `#define func _mm512_func`, or using some preprocessor tricks inside that one file.  Maybe another answer will have a better idea for this.

---

> I thought function pointers were preferred over macros in the C++ community. But this does the same job

Maybe if the function point is `void (*static const func_ptr)()` then you can count on it being inlined / optimized away.  You really don't want to add extra overhead for dispatching if you don't need it (e.g. for *runtime* CPU detection, setting functions pointers in an init function that runs `cpuid`)

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little on what you mean by compiling definitions selectively? Thanks.

Comment: @NanashiNoGombe: added an example.

Comment: Is there any overhead associated with defining a full-blown function (like you show) over say `#define func _mm512_func`?

Comment: Also, would it not be better to make these functions `inline`? Thanks again!

Comment: @NanashiNoGombe: If it's small, then yes you'd want to make it possible to inline.  Either by putting all that in a header and making the definitions `inline`, or by compiling with link-time optimization.  LTO is generally a good idea so I was assuming you'd do that.